# cant insert data to database laravel ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am new in laravel and there is problems occured
when i submit form using click function ajax jquery controller does not save data to database and everytime response with entire html file.
pleas help me.

some information about header

> Request URL:
>   http://akshay.laravel/patient1?fname=asdknkl&lname=nknkansd&email=knklansnd&sex=male&city=lknksn&state=klnklna&dob=2011-08-19&bloodtype=AB%2B&description=asak
>   Request Method: GET
>
> Status Code: 200 OK
>
> Remote Address: [::1]:80
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache, private
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Date: Thu, 12 Jul 2018 10:06:54 GMT
>
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/7.1.9
>
> Set-Cookie:
>   XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkFJRU1DQ3JhSWU2aWRMM0RXQlwvd0NBPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlpDN2pLdnVXQUV5b0lZRTlBUG95d3N6dDdXZEJ3ajBGU0g1NVwvaEFYak9PampDajcxQmVVZVhSZTUrVlNsTHhhbW9RWmdLOWNGWTdJNHpYdUhYV1N0Zz09IiwibWFjIjoiZDZiNzQyOGU1MWQxN2ZlZGNiZTkyMWU3NmZhYmMyY2FiMTQ5NGNkZDQ2OGQ3MzVlMzVjYjRhY2ZkMWMzNDg0NiJ9;
>   expires=Thu, 12-Jul-2018 12:06:54 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
>
> Set-Cookie:
>
> laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjFVK1RDZFlRajVtcWhcL0twNVhtS0NnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IllkWkdSSjlPY3pFeGNKSXBZNjVYRGE0TFU4TWxGZ2hwa3VYOGttdlVVM3lSUVFCakZDNFZUZGZkcUY5eFwvWHBOQVdsenY2S09kYlNWUktxY2x3VU1DUT09IiwibWFjIjoiN2VhZTEwNTAxY2YxNTZlNDAzZjJmNTNlYWJhYzcxYjBkY2I0NDZmNTc3N2ViZWU3NmY5Y2NmODg5MzllYWMzNiJ9;
>   expires=Thu, 12-Jul-2018 12:06:54 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.9
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Cookie: XSRF-
>   TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlBJcVpGRGw5VkN2VDVxTUcra1BzWkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZGhlT2Npc1Bjdm1PdG8xOThVR1wvbFJMbGdWTG5Pc2V1dDNFdlk0ekE0aFNVT0JTeHJBVzFIaEx2ZkFPK2l5bzdLZHUyYWU2RU5HK0ZcLzBsckRBY25QQT09IiwibWFjIjoiNWU2ZTFlN2EzZmQ5NDM4MzRhNDg3MjBhNTM2M2Q2MjhjOTdlMDRkODUzZTcxOTdhNDkyMTlkN2NlN2ZhNTJiNCJ9;
>   laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjJLSjUxNGdXZjJtaGptMmNjRFYyakE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRUlYVStKV1pTT3k3RWNYUytUMXVSN0FNV1ZXbzZzZUk3eDJZMXlKeTdkQlwvNWdqcjBGVWpjTFlTeVwvaGFtbmRKc3VmUklKN3ozeERzMjBxKytcLzQyQkE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjJjNTgyOGJlNzAyYTEzY2FjYmQzNTUxZDBmM2FmZGEyZWU4ZTE1OWY1MDdiNDcxYjExYjNkMzY4MjY5ZGQ0NmQifQ%3D%3D
>
> Host: akshay.laravel
>
> Referer: http://akshay.laravel/patient1
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99
>   Safari/537.36 X-CSRF-TOKEN: PIZIO18bZb7ce2M5taV04daMDFokJEHuIrZ88bkR
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>
> fname: asdknkl
>
> lname: nknkansd
>
> email: knklansnd
>
> sex: male
>
> city: lknksn
>
> state: klnklna
>
> dob: 2011-08-19
>
> bloodtype: AB+
>
> description: asak

php file:

```
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate id="patientform">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltip01">First name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First name" value="" required>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltip02">Last name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last name" value="" required>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltipUsername">Email</label>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text" id="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend">@</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="" aria-describedby="validationTooltipUsernamePrepend"
                                        required>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3"> 
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="male" name="sex" value="male" class="custom-control-input">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Male</label>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                            <input type="radio" id="female" name="sex" value="female" class="custom-control-input">
                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="female"> Female</label>
                                          </div>
                            </div>


                            @csrf

                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltip03">City</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" required>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltip04">State</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="State" required>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                                <label for="validationTooltip05">DOB</label>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="date" value="2011-08-19" id="dob">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3"> <br><br>
                                    <select class="custom-select" id="bloodtype">

                                            <option selected>Select Blood Type</option>
                                            <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                                            <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                                            <option value="A+">A+</option>
                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                            <option value="O+">O+</option>
                                            <option value="O-">O-</option>
                                          </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">

                                            <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Dieases / Description</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>

                                        </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submitform">Submit form</button>
                    </form>
```

controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
     /*  */ //
       function randomstring($len)
        {
            $string = "";
            $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
            for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++)
            $string.=substr($chars,rand(0,strlen($chars)),1);
            return $string;
        }
        $pid = randomstring(5);
        $fname = $request->fname;
        $lname = $request->lname;
        $email = $request->email;
        $sex = $request->sex;
        $city = $request->city;
        $state = $request->state;
        $dob = $request->dob;
        $bloodtype = $request->bloodtype;
        $description = $request->description;
  DB::table('tables')->insert(
            ['pid' => $pid, 'fname' => $fname,'lname' => $lname,'email' => $email,'sex' => $sex,'city' => $city,'state' => $state,'dob' => $dob,'bloodtype' => $bloodtype,'description' => $description,]
        );  
   //  $insert = DB::table('tables')->insert(['fname'=>$fname]);
     // echo $insert;
return redirect('table.admin');

    }
```

javascript file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#submitform" ).click(function() {
    var fname = $('#fname').val();
    var lname= $('#lname').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var sex = $('input[name="sex"]:checked').val();
    var city = $('#city').val();
    var state = $('#state').val();
    var dob = $('#dob').val();
    var bloodtype = $('#bloodtype').val();
    var description = $('#description').val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"/patient1/",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
      data:{
          'fname': fname,
          'lname': lname,
          'email': email,
          'sex': sex,
          'city': city,
          'state': state,
          'dob': dob,
          'bloodtype': bloodtype,
          'description': description 
      }
    });
});


});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you checked the erro rlog?

Comment: no error getting

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is a very safe environment, it wants you to use a CSRF Token
Insert this line of code below your form-tag

`{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: i have added {!! csrf_field() !!} but same result

Comment: If you go to the networking tab in your developer tools there should be a red item in the list where it went wrong, could you send me the preview of that item?

Comment: thanks all of you !   Problem solved i created another mvc